# UITextView receiving text form dictation, but text is nil in textView.text property

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to get the text from a UITextView whose entry method was dictation. In the `textViewDidChange` delegate method, I have tried printing the following info:

```
 print(textView.text)
 print(myTextView.text)
 print(textView.hasText)
 print(textView.attributedText)
 print(textView.textStorage)
```

all of these come back nil, except the `hasText` comes back as false.

The text is visible right there in the textView, but it is not being registered. I should say that when I  go edit another form in the field, and then try to get the value from this text field, then the the text entered IS visible in the textView's textView.text property. But it's like it takes a few moments of editing other fields to fully "register" with the textView object.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: did you set the delegate of the UITextView ?

Comment: yes indeed, all delegate methods are called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this after a while

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
   print(textView.text)
   print(textView.hasText)
   print(textView.hasText)
   print(textView.attributedText)
   print(textView.textStorage)
}
```

Update: It`s because you are trying to print the text before setting it. It takes a little time to set your text into textView.